# Remodelling a dataframe in R

Tags: r, dplyr, statistics, data.table, data-modeling

I am trying to remodel my data into the following (from the left shape to the right shape):
[image]

Below is the reproducible initial dataframe:

```
  df <- data.frame(tag=c("tech","tech","tech","tech","distribution","fooddrinks","industry","conseil","tech","tech","conseil","fooddrinks","tech","conseil","conseil","conseil","conseil"),
                     company_name=c("360Learning","365Talents","3DS OUTSCALE","4D SAS","77 Foods","77 Foods","77 Foods","8pourcent","8SEC","Compte Pour Moi","Compte Pour Moi","AB InBev Europe","AB Tasty","AB Tasty","ABBD","Abbeal","ABC arbitrage"),
    company_link=c("/fr/companies/360learning",  "/fr/companies/365talents",  "/fr/companies/3dsoutscale",  "/fr/companies/4d",  "/fr/companies/77-foods",  "/fr/companies/77-foods",  "/fr/companies/77-foods",  "/fr/companies/8pourcent",  "/fr/companies/8sec",  "/fr/companies/ca-compte-pour-moi",  "/fr/companies/ca-compte-pour-moi",  "/fr/companies/abinbev",
      "/fr/companies/ab-tasty",  "/fr/companies/ab-tasty",  "/fr/companies/abbd",  "/fr/companies/abbeal",  "/fr/companies/abc-arbitrage"))
```

I have tried the following functions: `stats::reshape`, `data.table::dcast`, `tidyr::spread` but I can't figure out the proper way to use them nor if they are the right ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not really trying to reshape (that would be adding columns based on the content of rows), here you just want to `summarize` the `tag` values for each `company`. So that can be done easily with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(company_name, company_link) %>%
  summarize(tag = paste(tag, collapse = ", "))
```

Answer (score 0):

When using `data.table`, you could also solve your problem as follows:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)[, .(tag = toString(tag), company_link = company_link[1]), by = company_name]

#        company_name                                tag                     company_link
#  1:     360Learning                               tech        /fr/companies/360learning
#  2:      365Talents                               tech         /fr/companies/365talents
#  3:    3DS OUTSCALE                               tech        /fr/companies/3dsoutscale
#  4:          4D SAS                               tech                 /fr/companies/4d
#  5:        77 Foods distribution, fooddrinks, industry           /fr/companies/77-foods
#  6:       8pourcent                            conseil          /fr/companies/8pourcent
#  7:            8SEC                               tech               /fr/companies/8sec
#  8: Compte Pour Moi                      tech, conseil /fr/companies/ca-compte-pour-moi
#  9: AB InBev Europe                         fooddrinks            /fr/companies/abinbev
# 10:        AB Tasty                      tech, conseil           /fr/companies/ab-tasty
# 11:            ABBD                            conseil               /fr/companies/abbd
# 12:          Abbeal                            conseil             /fr/companies/abbeal
# 13:   ABC arbitrage                            conseil      /fr/companies/abc-arbitrage
```